# Batch script to copy/rename files

Tags: bash, debian

Hi I want to make a batch script to transform:

```
/VAR/file.css
```

into

```
/VAR_file.css`
```

`VAR` is an ID. I need to make a loop  for `i=0` to `i<=36000`

Any ideas?

I have never manipulated batch script..

Answer (score 0):

You can create the sequence from `0` to `36000` with the `{0..X}` expression and move the files:

```
for i in {0..36000}
do
  mv "/$i/file.css" "/${i}_file.css"
done
```

Comment: you have to create the file (using vi, for instance), save the content and then give executing mode to it (chmod +x file). You'd better check a basic guide like the one @Martin Skøtt suggested you.

Comment: @Anthony I was going through old answers... Did this work to you?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `seq 0 36000`
do
    for file in /$i/*.css
    do
        mv /$i/$file /$i_$file
    done
done
```

Comment: ssh user@host 'for i in `seq 0 36000`; do; for file in /$i/*.css; do; mv /$i/$file /$i_$file; done; done;'